# LFTP: Mirror to remote except particular file present on remote

Tags: mirror, lftp

I usually edit my website locally and push it with this command:

```
lftp -u user,password host -e "mirror -c -e -R -x ^\.git/$ my /my; exit"
```

But now, my website dynamically appends data to the `/my/data` file.

I don't have this `/my/data` file locally.

**QUESTION:** How to push without deleting `/my/data` and its content?

Notes:

- I could download `/my/data` and then run the command above, but data added in the few seconds before the download and the upload would get lost.
- For the other files/folders, local deletion should be mirrored by a remote deletion.
- I don't want to use `--only-newer`-like operations because clocks might not be adjusted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer given by LFTP's maintainer:

Just exclude the folder using `-x ^data/` option.

If you need to upload some local files into that folder, use two mirrors,
one without `-e` option just for `my/data` folder.

Comment: How do I skip multiple files and directories?

Comment: @Ikechukwu: I have not tried, but maybe multiple `-x` arguments?

Comment: I confirm that you can use multiples `-x` (`--exclude`) and/or multiples `-X` (`--exclude-glob`).

Answer (score 0):

"Just exclude the folder using -x ^data/ option."

Can i ask dumb question about the '^' caracter? what did it does?
I just figure out that without it mirror still ignore the named folder in both sides (host and remote)
I 1st thought that it means "ignore data folder in the remote side (only)"

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/444848)

Comment: Probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended

Comment: `-x` takes an "*extended regular expression, just like in egrep*" as its argument according to https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html, so @nicolas is right: it means the start of the path. Otherwise `data/` would match anywhere